# SSRS Report not showing lines

Tags: reporting-services, line

I have a report with a series of lines within a Tablix. The problem is these lines do not show on screen through the ReportViewer on as ASP.NET page, but if I export I see them just fine.

Any ideas?

This is Report Viewer 2010.

Comment: I have concluded that this is a bug in the report viewer as no one seems to know the reason why. One work around for right angles is to use a rectangle will only one edge showing and then shrinking the rectangle to fit the space I wanted the line to appear in.

Answer (score 4):

Make the border width as minimum of 0.75pt and the borders will appear. Its a weird issue. Changing the border width is working for me.

Comment: In my case I had to change it to 2pt and they showed up.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar weird issue where a line showed up correctly on the report, but was missing in the printed report, including the print preview. After a bunch of troubleshooting **I finally determined that if the line or text box goes all the way to the right side of the report, it disappears when you try to print it**. But if you bring it back just a bit from the edge, it shows up fine.

I have no idea why this happens, but hopefully this tip will help someone else out there that might experience a similar issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the shrinking rectangle issue, try placing an invisible line there, too, that is the width that the rectangle needs to be.

Also... leaving small spaces, particularly on the left and bottom edges of the report, prevent the margins from cutting off borders and edges of report objects.  Just about the height of one of these letter's I'm typing now does it.  I learned to leave this gap when trying to get a footer to format correctly.  And I noticed anything I placed against the left margin got cut off, too, when in the report viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I just had an issue with it not showing a line and fixed it by wrapping the field expression with a CInt() to convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I had the same issue.  My fix was to set the property of the matrix textbox to CanGrow = True.

I tried all of the other suggestions and found that was the only thing different between one that worked and the one that wasn't.

[image: Textbox property]